# scraping Images off Ebay

Tags: php, xpath, curl, xquery

I am trying to scrap  a list of products off ebay.I can get all the information except the Image source. My query retrieves all the the information of the image ie  alt,height,etc but does not retrieve the source.

```
One of the product link I am trying to scrape.
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/REAR-RAISED-KING-SPRINGS-2-03-ON-TOYOTA-L-CRUISER-PRADO-120-150-GX-KTPR-102-/170945971135?pt=AU_Car_Parts_Accessories&hash=item27cd2c83bf

Query I used
$query1=".//*[@id='i_vv4-35']";

Test to chek if attribute exist  returns nothing.
$element1->hasAttribute('src')

Get attribute method.
 $element1->getAttribute('src')
```

Regards
Abnab

Comment: don't steal, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

That is because eBay, probably in an attempt to stop you and others doing what you're trying to do, don't actually use an `<img>` element. The image is an `<a>` element with a background set to the image:

```
background: url(http://q.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/s.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
```

You'll need to parse the css and pull the background property from the declaration for the element you're finding.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. <a> has javascript attached to it.  You can see the image tag in the above div of that link.